# Añadir información a un diccionario vacío

Tags: python

estoy intentando realizar un bucle que vaya insertando mucha información a un diccionario, y a partir de ahí crearlo y pasarlo a formato JSON. Toda esta información la estoy extrayendo mediante scrape desde TikTok. Este es mi código. Mi duda es como realizar la inserción de los datos que voy extrayendo al diccionario, donde estos datos son video_info que utilizo para sacar en json para realizar un prueba.

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
import asyncio
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

ms_token = os.environ.get("x", None)  # token generado desde TikTok ads manager

p='"'

datos=pd.read_excel("videos.xlsx", converters={'Cuenta':str, 'URL':str})
#datos=pd.read_excel("videos_todos.xlsx", converters={'Cuenta':str, 'URL':str})


lista=[]
for i in range(len(datos)):
    lista.append(str(datos.iloc[i]['URL']))

dicc={}

async def get_video_example():
    async with TikTokApi() as api:
        await api.create_sessions(ms_tokens=[ms_token], num_sessions=1, sleep_after=3)
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            video = api.video(url=lista[i])

            async for related_video in video.related_videos(count=2):
                print(related_video)
                print(related_video.as_dict)

            video_info = await video.info()  # is HTML request, so avoid using this too much
            print(video_info)
            #with open( ("myfile"+"_"+str([i])+".json"), "w") as j:
            #   json.dump(video_info, j)
            dicc[video_info]
            dicc



if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(get_video_example())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma seria utilizando la url como clave del diccionario para almacenar la información del video. No he podido probar el código.

`dicc[url] = info_video` o `dicc[lista[i]] = info_video`